# How to edit checkout page?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

[image: checkout image]

how to edit this text "thank you your order has been received"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the file "/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php" to your theme or child theme ("/yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php").

And then you will find this code

```
esc_html__( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' )
```

Change it to whatever you like.